# How do I read an external JSON file hosted on a site from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I read a JSON file that is hosted on another server?
There is a site which hosts JSON data and I want to access it through JavaScript.
The JSON data is on the [Open Notify API](http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json).

The problem with other questions asked and things I found on the Internet don't help me because they're all about **local JSON files**!

I also tried jQuery but it didn't work. Anyways, when I looked at the syntax, the *script* part of the function had to be a PHP script on the server. I put the JSON file in that spot but nothing happened. I used the `$.get()` method.

I would really appreciate it if someone answered me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pretty much the same manner you'd call a local JSON file, you can fetch the contents of an online JSON file from another URL.

That being said, you should keep in mind that the URL should provide cross-origin headers to allow your domain to request that resource.

The [URL you mentioned](http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json) has those headers and you can use it. However, their web server doesn't support HTTPS so I can't use it as an example here, thus I will use [this JSON](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) for the sake of the example:

```js
$.getJSON(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
  function( data ) {
     $('div#title span').html(data.title);
     $('div#completed span').html(data.completed?'true':'false');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='title'>Title: <span></span></div>
<div id='completed'>Completed: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this example is using a call via HTTP. Just make sure the cross origin headers are set to allow your domain to request the resource(s) you are trying to obtain.